Вводное слово на границе частей СПП
Мы сделаем это, конечно(,) если нам никто не помешает.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли запятая после вводного слова в данном случае? Учитывая правило о том, что вводные слова не обособляются на границе частей сложного предложения. В каких случаях это правило применимо?

Правильно:
Мы сделаем это, конечно, если нам никто не помешает.
Пояснение

Розенталь, пункт 7
7. Если между главной и придаточной частями 
сложноподчиненного предложения стоит вводное слово, то 
оно выделяется запятыми на общих основаниях: Он подумал, 
возможно, что я не хочу с ним встречаться; Если есть 
спрос на что-либо, значит, будет и предложение.

Отнесение вводного слова по смыслу к главной или 
придаточной части определяется условиями контекста. Ср.: 
Он сердился, по-видимому, потому что лицо его было 
возбуждённым — вводное слово относится к главной части 
(возбужденное лицо может быть следствием, а не причиной 
состояния субъекта); Он торопился потому, по-видимому, 
что боялся опоздать на заседание — вводное слово 
относится к придаточной части, о чем свидетельствует 
расчлененность сложного подчинительного союза. [См. § 34, 
п. 2.]



Розенталь § 25. Вводные слова и словосочетания
 7. Вводное слово (сочетание), стоящее перед 
 сравнительным оборотом (с союзом как), целевым 
 оборотом (с союзом чтобы) и т. д., отделяется от 
 них запятой на основании общего правила: Всё это 
 мне показалось странным, впрочем, как и другим; 
 Студент на минуту задумался, вероятно, чтобы 
 точнее сформулировать свой ответ. Обычно в этих 
 случаях вводное слово относится к последующей 
 части предложения.


Для больше определенности вводное слово можно разместить внутри  придаточного:

Мы сделаем это, если, конечно, нам никто не помешает.

Вводные слова могут не обособляться в БСП (правило Лопатина),

§ 94. Лось шел скачками в сторону озер, должно быть спешил на водопой (Пауст.); Послышался резкий стук, должно быть сорвалась ставня (Ч.).
Но Розенталь предлагает другое решение (в случае неясности добавлять тире): Розенталь § 43. Запятая и точка с запятой в бессоюзном сложном предложении (п.3)
